# Jetpack compose play remote audio through URL

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have been able to use MediaPlayer to play a local file in drawable but could not figure out how to play a remote file.  Could not find relevant info from the internet too.

Below is what I have come out but it doesn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val url = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3"
    Button(onClick = {
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
            AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build()
        )

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(url))
            mediaPlayer.prepare()
            mediaPlayer.start()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }) {
        Text(text = "Play")
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works for me. It plays the audio when I click the button.

Comment: Really, let me try again!

Comment: @ArpitShukla, yes yes it works!  I just have to first clean and restart the simulator.  Please answer so that I can award you the points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the above code and it works fine for me. Try again with a different device or restart the emulator (if you are testing on an emulator).

One optimisation that you can do here is to replace `prepare` with `prepareAsync`. `prepare` will block the UI thread. Fetching audio from Internet takes some time and UI will remain unresponsive till then. `prepareAsync`, on the other hand, does the preparation on a background thread.

```kotlin
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener { mp ->
    mp.start()
}
```